# Recurring payments IPN

Tags: payment, paypal, paypal-ipn, recurring-billing

Working on implementation of paypal's recurring payments, I've got encountered some problems. I have followed paypal's documentation from here: 
[PayPal Express Checkout: Recurring Payments Process Flow](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide/RecurringPayments.html#2573120)

It seems that everything works properly and I get ProfileID at the end (from result of `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile()` query). Recurring profile is also being created.

The problem is there's no IPN confirmation after running `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile()` , but according to:
[PayPal Express Checkout: PayPal Notifications](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide/RecurringPayments.html#2576456) - it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience this happens only when IPN (Instant Payment Notifications) are not enabled in your merchant account. You can enable IPN in Profile > Instant Payment Notification Preferences.